# Solar energy in a specific location

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, geophysics, renewable-energy

How to find the amount of solar power in a specific location on Earth per month?

By solar power I mean the energy received from the sun in a squared meter.

Comment: You need to look up "monthly solar insolation" data for the region you are interested in. For the US it can be found here: http://www.nrel.gov/gis/solar.html/

Comment: It would help to tell is where you are - then people might be able to suggest datasets, as somebody already has for the US.

Comment: I live in Tehran, Iran.@SimonW

Answer (score 1):

Many sites focused on solar energy production can provide you with the desired information.

One example is http://www.solarelectricityhandbook.com/solar-irradiance.html which provides you with the monthly solar insolation for a country and city of your choice. In addition to a surface lying flat on the ground, the value is also provided for different orientation of surfaces.

[image]

(Screen shot of http://www.solarelectricityhandbook.com/solar-irradiance.html)